# phonegap ios not playing recorded wav

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, media, record

I was successful recording
But
It failed to play the file.
My xcode output message
'Finished recording audio sample'
'recording.wav'
I think that the problem of the media path
So I entered a variety of paths
file://private...,
file://var/...,
filesystem...
What should I do?

```
function getPhoneGapPath() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
    return "file://"+path;
};

var resource = getPhoneGapPath() + 'recording.wav';
var fileURL ;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play").click(function(){
        alert(resource)
        var play = new Media(resource,
        function(){
            alert("success")
        },
        function(err){
            alert("err:"+err)
        })
        play.play();
    })
})

var mediaRec;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    var src = "recording.wav"
    mediaRec = new Media(src,
    function(){
        console.log("success")
    },
    function(err){
        alert("err:"+err)
    })

    mediaRec.startRecord();

    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");

        if (recTime >= 2) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function setAudioPosition(position){
    document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mediaRec.play()
```

but for iOS media capture is the good plugin for recording  [Media capture](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture)

Comment: So you say that on iOS we can't record using almost the same code we used on android? From what I know, media capture plugin opens the phone recorder, and some people want to make a recorder in the app.

Comment: @lonut From media capture plugin Doc  : iOS does not have a default audio recording application, so a simple user interface is provided. [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#ios-quirks)

Comment: You misunderstood me. I was talking about using the media plugin, not media capture plugin. They're not the same. The guy who asked the question also used media plugin, not media-capture plugin.